# Getting wrong value for AM/PM from 12:00 to 12:59 when converting from 24-hour format to 12 hour format in Kotlin Android (Minimum Android Version 21)

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, time

My extension function:

```
    fun String.formatDate(): String {
        val outputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a")
        return outputFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(this))
    }
```

When I send "2021-11-03 12:02:12", I get "Nov 03, 2021 12:02 AM"

It should be "Nov 03, 2021 12:02 PM" instead. (refer image below)

[image]

Comment: Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It makes such trouble as this, and many other kinds too. Switch to java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: `return LocalDateTime.parse(this, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH))` to get `Nov 03, 2021 12:02 PM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed. There was a minor error.

I was using `hh` as input format, which is 12-hour format. I needed to use `HH` instead.

`return outputFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US).parse(this))`